# How to position a div inside another div in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I want to put the children div on end of parent div , but positioning is not working. i'm using reactJs, NextJs and styled-components for this code;

reactjs code:

```
<a href={links[indexImg]} target="_blank" >
    <Carousel
        image={images[indexImg]}
    >
        <DescriptionText>
            <p>{descriptions[indexImg]}</p>
        </DescriptionText>
    </Carousel>
</a>
```

styled-componentes code:

```
export const DescriptionText = styled.div`
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    background-position: 20px;
    opacity: 0.5;
`;
export const Carousel = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #C2C2C2;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-image:url(${props => props.image});
`;
```

Comment: Include to DescriptionText position:absolute along with bottom: 0

Comment: Or into Carousel, just.. display:flex; flex-direction: column;

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!
I was trying to use position absolute in DescriptionText but i was using self-align.

Comment: These two approaches will fit, but option two will plays better when deal with cross resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.inner` division has a position of `absolute` and your `.outer` one gets position `relative`, the `.inner` division will adjust itself inside the `.outer` one. For example: if you want the `.inner` one to stick to the bottom of the `.outer` one you can do this:

```
.outer {
    position: relative
}
.inner {
    postion: absolute;
    bottom: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all install bootstrap from terminal using the command

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

suppose you are working with components like Leftsidebar.js , Rightsidebar.js and Content.js  which you have imported to index.js

to do this you have install bootstrap in your react.js

follow the steps

index.js blow

```
import React from 'react';
   import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
   import Leftsidebar from './Leftsidebar';
   import Rightsidebar from './Rightsidebar';
   import Content from './Content';
    
    ReactDom.render(
    
    // outer most div
    <div class='row'>
    
    <div class='col-4'>
    <Leftsidebar/>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class='col-4'>
    <Content/>
    </div>
    
    <div class='col-4'>
    <Rightsidebar/>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    ,documment.getelementbyId('root');
    );
```

simple we have used the grid system to divide the screen into 4 different part out of 12 secondly the above code is just typed in the text editor .but my aim was to guide you how to show data in different layout or positions using react js and it work because i myself use row column to arrange data in position and it is the easiest method .

Comment: Problem here is to use another framework to solve a single problem, think it won't makes a clean code.